# Finding number of child processes

Tags: bash, process, pid

How do find the number of child processes of a bash script, from within the script itself?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

To obtain the PID of the bash script you can use variable `$$`.

Then, to obtain its children, you can run:

```
bash_pid=$$
children=`ps -eo ppid | grep -w $bash_pid`
```

`ps` will return the list of parent PIDs. Then `grep` filters all the processes not related to the bash script's children. In order to get the number of children you can do:

```
num_children=`echo $children | wc -w`
```

Actually the number you will get will be off by 1, since `ps` will be a child of the bash script too. If you do not want to count the execution of `ps` as a child, then you can just fix that with:

```
let num_children=num_children-1
```

**UPDATE:** In order to avoid calling `grep`, the following syntax might be used (if supported by the installed version of `ps`):

```
num_children=`ps --no-headers -o pid --ppid=$$ | wc -w`
```

Comment: `grep -w $bash_pid` in case the bash pid is a substring of a child's process ID.

Comment: Not sure, but I think the extra process is the subshell that contains the ps/grep pipeline. Just being pedantic :)

Comment: No need for `grep`: `ps -o ppid= -p $$` (at least with GNU `ps`).

Comment: @chepner I was not sure either, so I just did a quick check. I created a small script containing `foo=$(sleep 10 | wc -l)`. Then I checked with `ps` and both `sleep` and `wc` were listed as direct children of the script (i.e., no new shell in between).

Comment: Oh, sorry, I forgot for a moment that the OP was looking for the children and I overlooked the progression of your step-wise answer.

Comment: But how do I get count of all descendants of a process? This just gives immediate child count

Answer (score 12):

I prefer:

`num_children=$(pgrep -c -P$$)`

It spawns just one process, you do not have to count words or adjust the numbers of PIDs by the programs in the pipe.

Example:

```
~ $ echo $(pgrep -c -P$$)
0
~ $ sleep 20 &
[1] 26114
~ $ echo $(pgrep -c -P$$)
1
```

Comment: This answer looks pretty concise and clean to me, it should probably be the accepted one.

Answer (score 6):

You can also use pgrep:

`child_count=$(($(pgrep --parent $$ | wc -l) - 1))`

Use `pgrep --parent $$` to get a list of the children of the bash process.
Then use `wc -l` on the output to get the number of lines: `$(pgrep --parent $$ | wc -l)`
Then subtract 1 (`wc -l` reports 1 even when `pgrep --parent $$` is empty)

Answer (score 5):

If job count (instead of pid count) is enough I just came with a bash-only version:

```
job_list=($(jobs -p))
job_count=${#job_list[@]}
```

Comment: your solution works also on BusyBox (Alpine Linux)

Answer (score 2):

Use `ps` with the `--ppid` option to select children of the current bash process.

```
bash_pid=$$
child_count=$(ps -o pid= --ppid $bash_id | wc -l)
let child_count-=1    # If you don't want to count the subshell that computed the answer
```

(Note: this requires the Linux version of `ps` for `--ppid`. I don't know if there is an equivalent for BSD `ps` or not.)

Comment: Doesn't work for me.  Gives me a `ps: illegal option -- -`.  Perhaps you are assuming a particular version of ps?

Comment: Yes, I was assuming the version used by Linux.

Comment: Ah.  I tested on FreeBSD and OSX.

Answer (score -3):

You may evaluate the shell builtin command jobs like:

```
counter = `jobs | wc -l`
```

Comment: That counts jobs, not processes. A job can consist of multiple processes.

Comment: No spaces around the equal sign. Use `$()` instead of backticks.